# how to add treeview class to listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, casting, listbox, treeview

I have a wpf add treeview item to listbox like follows:

```
    private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemToAdd = this.tv_Project.SelectedItem as Product;
        if(itemToAdd != null)
        {
            lb_Configuration.Items.Add(itemToAdd);
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

the listbox binding to ItemsSource like:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb_Configuration" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}">
```

The above code works fine. Now when I detect the `RegisterLowByte` has the same `ModelNumber` as `Products`, I want to add the corresponding `Product` to the listbox automaticlly, so I tried this:

```
    private void FindDevice_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var RegisterLowByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(infoRegisters[j])[0];
        var hasItem = sdb.GetProductFilteredWithLinq(RegisterLowByte) as Product;
        if (hasItem != null)
        {
            lb_Configuration.Items.Add(hasItem);
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

The method to get product:

```
    public ICollection<Product> GetProductFilteredWithLinq(UInt16 modelNumber)
    {
        ICollection<Product> products = GetProducts();

        IEnumerable<Product> matches = from product in products
                                       where product.ModelNumber == modelNumber
                                       select product;

        return new ObservableCollection<Product>(matches.ToList());
    }
```

After I tried this, the `hasItem` always be null, but if I try to define `hasItem` like

```
var hasItem = sdb.GetProductFilteredWithLinq(RegisterLow).Cast<Product>();
```

I can get the `Product` which has the same `ModelNumber` as `RegisterLowByte` but I can't add this to listbox as `Product`, any one knows how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetProductFilteredWithLinq returning the collection so you need to use [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of Add.

```
 private void FindDevice_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {    
        var RegisterLowByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(infoRegisters[j])[0];
        var hasItem = sdb.GetProductFilteredWithLinq(RegisterLow);
        if (hasItem != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in hasItem)
            {
              lb_Configuration.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: `lb_Configuration` is a **ItemCollection** which doesn't have `AddRange`